# Plotting multiple ROC curves on the same graph with for loop

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc

I am using a for loop to evaluate different models and generate an ROC curve.  I have the below code but it always plots the same color for each ROC curve, which makes the graph not very readable.

```
models = {
"KNN": KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 10),
"Logistic Regression": LogisticRegression(),
"Decision Tree": DecisionTreeClassifier(),
"SVM": SVC(probability=True)}

for name, model in models.items():
    model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    y_scores = model.predict_proba(X_test_scaled)
    fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(y_test, y_scores[:, 1])
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)


plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()
```

I am thinking of creating another list of colors and using that in the for loop but I cannot quite figure it out.  Does it need to be in the same list?  Is there an easier/more elegant way to do it than what I'm thinking of?

Comment: because you have given the color blue option, remove this from you plot will be fine `b,`

Comment: Thank you!  Very obvious now but a fresh set of eyes really helped.